# Computer not turning on after replacing CPU, PSU, and motherboard

Tags: cpu, power-supply, desktop-computer

I would seriously appreciate any help here. I had a game running overnight on my computer and when I came back it was off. I tried turning it on and only the case fans run. I have replaced the PSU, the motherboard and the PSU but it’s still not turning on.
I’ve tried a new graphics card as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any POST beep codes? Have you attached all the power connectors properly (ATX and the 4/8-pin CPU power cable)?

Comment: Generally in HW troubleshooting you should swap/change only one component at a time to better nail down the faulty one. Does the PSU run in paperclip test at least?